# Problem with implementing View in scrollview Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scrollview, swift5

I want to do something like this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1_daE3IL_1s

But unfortunately the code doesnt work.

```
class minViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var scroll: UIScrollView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let minjung : minViewController = minViewController(nibName: "minViewController", bundle: nil)

        self.addChild(minjung)
        self.scroll.addSubview(minjung.view)
        minjung.didMove(toParent: self)

    }




}
```

Any ideas on how to do this in Swift 5?

Also in general: Should I just switch to an older version of swift? I am a beginner and most tutorials I find online are using older versions.

Comment: https://medium.com/@anitaa_1990/create-a-horizontal-paging-uiscrollview-with-uipagecontrol-swift-4-xcode-9-a3dddc845e92 Going through the link will be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

You initialize `minViewController` inside `minViewController`. Check out your video.